# Trying to recreate a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to recreate a very beutiful recycler view that i found on this github:
https://github.com/saulmm/Material-Movies
The thing is that I even thought i've copy pasted all of the necessary code it seems diferent
Here's a side to side picture of how it is against how it should be.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar7ld.jpg

//edit:

Layout Activity: http://pastebin.com/bNSSMW61

Layout Activityw600dp: http://pastebin.com/shLsX4EW

Layout Recycler : http://pastebin.com/XcdRbvk5

Activity: http://pastebin.com/fRCvCZDH

// Updated: 
Adapter: http://pastebin.com/uyYdPqrY

AutoFitRecyclerView: http://pastebin.com/uhKaBEQH

RecyclerInsetsDecoration: http://pastebin.com/w0AH51t3

Is there a way to easy diagnost the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decorating RecyclerView (with GridLayoutManager) to display divider between items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146781/decorating-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-to-display-divider-between-item)

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek the thing is that I have the exact code has [link](https://github.com/saulmm/Material-Movies/blob/9dea7fafe17932bb4fafc5f07bfedf7042937536/HackVG/app/src/main/java/com/hackvg/android/utils/RecyclerInsetsDecoration.java) and I already debugged side by side and it dosen't look the same

Comment: That decorator uses dimensions that are stored in a resource file. Make sure that you have all of the dimensions in https://github.com/saulmm/Material-Movies/blob/9dea7fafe17932bb4fafc5f07bfedf7042937536/HackVG/app/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml

Comment: yes I even copied paste the dimensions files as precaution :/ I changed the rvadapter to fix another bug, the code is on the pastebin above. I noticed that the variables had some diferences like this: imgur.com/a/00zz3 @GreyBeardedGeek

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I Copied and pasted everything from my code to the working code and It does work on the other project. I think it is because the other project(the one from github) is using a old gradle. Can it affect?