# Custom Item decore for Recycler view with grid layout manager in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, item-decoration

How can I implement a custom Item decore for recycler view with grid layout manager.
I am using a recycler view with grid layout manager.

I want to implement the item decore like this,

[image]

found these results from stackoverflow, but want to implement custom 
[Decorating RecyclerView (with GridLayoutManager) to display divider between items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146781/decorating-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-to-display-divider-between-item)

Comment: may it will help you ---- please check ---- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23891978/7344185

Answer (score 1):

You could add item decoration, each time when callback fires you could check item position and draw what you want. [Doc link.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#onDrawOver(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State))