# how to set RecyclerView vertical divider with GridLayoutManager same as horizontal vertical

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` set to a vertical `GridLayoutManager`

`shelfRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2));`

elements inside the recyclerview have fixed width and height using `sdp` so the horizontal divider width is fixed too.

[image]

is there any way to get the width of the horizontal divider and set the vertical divider width as the same as that?

Comment: For divider to be same your item's height has to be same as `RecyclerView` excluding horizontal margins .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing a custom [ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration) which adds equal horizontal and vertical space to each item.
Here are some samples to get you started
[Decorating RecyclerView (with GridLayoutManager) to display divider between items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146781/decorating-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-to-display-divider-between-item)

https://gist.github.com/UweTrottmann/c6344c32aa61d1bec5a6