# No margin between my items from my recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

There is no white space between my items in my list. I tried adding margin on multiple places but nothing seems to work, and I don't know why.

[image]

I'm sorry if my XML pages are messy, but it's my first time making an app.
My activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/overviewFragment"
    android:name="com.example.breweries.overview.OverviewFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_overview" />
```

My fragment_overview

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.breweries.overview.OverviewViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.example.breweries.overview.OverViewFragment">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/photos_grid"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:spanCount="1"
            app:listData="@{viewModel.photos}"
            tools:itemCount="8"
            tools:listitem="@layout/grid_view_item"
            />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

My grid_view_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layout >
    <data>
        <variable
            name="photo"
            type="com.example.breweries.network.Brewery" />

    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Any other tips to make my XML pages better are highly appreciated!

Comment: Remove the `android:layout_margin="20dp"` and change `android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"`  to `android:layout_margin="20dp"`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168276/3815660 
Read carefully and try `ItemDecorator` to achieve it for `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line

```
android:layout_margin="5dp"
```

You **xml** will look like this.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```